# Saving arrays in core data

Tags: arrays, swift, core-data

I am trying to make an app where i take in input from users and store it in an array for later use. 
I have saved the user input in `numToEnter` 
here is my code

```
    var nums = [NSManagedObject]()

    @IBAction func logMood(_ sender: UIButton) {


                let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
                let managedObjectContext = delegate.persistentContainer.viewContext


                let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Numbers",
                                                         in:managedObjectContext)
                num.setValue(numToEnter, forKey: "numberToSave")

                let num = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!,
                                          insertInto: managedObjectContext) 

        do {
            try managedObjectContext.save()
            nums.append(num)
        } catch let error as NSError  {
            print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
```

here is the numbers class

```
class nsobjNumbers: NSObject {

    static let sharedInstance = Numbers()
    var number: NSNumber = 0
    var dataOfArray: [[Int: Int]] =  [[Int: Int]]()

}
```

[and here is the XCDataModel](https://imgur.com/gallery/d8UWq6G)

errors 
1. error: CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'Numbers'
2. CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'Numbers'
3. Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Numbers dataOfArray]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: what is the problem u r facing ?

Comment: error: CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'Numbers' and error and error: error: CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'Numbers'

Comment: That code doesn't even compile, you call `num.setValue` before you declare `let num`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you cannot use a singleton because you have to insert the `Numbers` instances into the managed object context. This is the *Failed to call designated initializer* error.

---

As the attribute `dataOfArray` is declared as binary data I recommend to add a computed property in the `Numbers` class and de-/encode the array from and to JSON

```
var dataArray : [[Int: Int]] {
    get { return (try? JSONDecoder().decode([[Int:Int]].self, from: dataOfArray)) ?? [] }
    set { dataOfArray = try! JSONEncoder().encode(newValue) }
}
```

Amazingly `JSONEncoder` encodes the integer keys implicitly to `String` and `JSONDecoder` decodes them back to `Int`

---

Nowadays it's highly recommended to take advantage of the generic skills of Core Data, declare `nums` as the `NSManagedObject` subclass

```
var nums = [Numbers]()
```

and change `logMood` to

```
@IBAction func logMood(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedObjectContext = delegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let num =  Numbers(context: managedObjectContext)
    num.numberToSave = numToEnter
    do {
        try managedObjectContext.save()
        nums.append(num)
    } catch let error as NSError  {
        print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

To save the array to Core Data assign it to `dataArray` and save the context for example

```
num.dataArray = [[1:2, 3:4]]
do {
   try managedObjectContext.save()
```

The computed property does the conversion from and to `Data`

Comment: the object num doesn't contain dataArray, right? also where should i declare num.dataArray = [[1:2, 3:4]]
do {
   try managedObjectContext.save() }

Comment: This is only an example. I don't know where the attribute `dataOfArray` is going to be used.